# Detect user's mouse click and enter key press

Tags: c#

I have a little problem that needs your ideas, I am building a simple application to detect when user finishes writing text into a textbox, there is a button the user can click or press the enter key to proceed further action

[**UPDATE**]

Oh I am sorry, I have to add that the textbox is from another windows, it may be any windows.

I don't want to use function like GetAsyncKeyState which is an ugly method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Control.KeyPress Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx)

```
this.textBox1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(CheckKeys);

private void CheckKeys(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
          // Then Enter key was pressed
    }
 }
```

(char)13 means the Enter key.